# how to create a multi-dimensional array that every level keyname is named by developer

Tags: php

I need to write a method which returns a multi-dimensional array. The number of array depth is determined by the number of times the method is called.

```
class Maker
{
    public $array = [];
    function set($key, $value = [])
    {
        //make the array
    }
}

$maker = new Maker();
$maker->set('a');
$maker->set('b');
$maker->set('c', 100);

print_r($maker->array);
```

The result is:
    array(
        'a' => 
            'b' => 
                'c' => 100
     )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with recursion

```
class Maker
{
  public $array = [];

  function set($key, $value = []) {
    $this->_set($this->array, $key, $value);
  }

  private function _set(&$array, $key, $value) {
    if (is_array($array)) {
      if (empty($array))
        $array[$key] = $value;
      else {
        foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
          $this->_set($array[$k], $key, $value);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [b] => Array
                (
                    [c] => 100
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
class Maker
{
    private $arrayContainer = []; // Make public if you want to access it `$maker->arrayContainer`
    function set(string $key, $value = [])
    {
        $this->arrayContainer[$key] = $value;
    }
    function get(string $key,$default=null){
        return isset($this->arrayContainer[$key])?$this->arrayContainer[$key]:$default;
    }
    function all(){
        return $this->arrayContainer;
    }
}
$maker = new Maker();
$maker->set('a');
$maker->set('b', [1,2,3,4,5]);
$maker->set('c', ['a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3]);

//Get a specific index from the Maker class
print_r($maker->get('b'));

//Get the arrayContainer from the Maker Class
print_r($maker->all());
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more suitable

```
 class Maker
{
    public $array = [];
    function set($key, $value = [])
    {
        $this->array[$key] = $value;
    }
}

$maker = new Maker();
$maker->set('a', array( 'VAL1', 1 ));
$maker->set('b', array( 'VAL1', array ( 'VAL2', 2 ) ));
$maker->set('c' , array( 'VAL1', array ( 'VAL2', array ( 'VAL3', 3 )  ) ));

var_dump($maker->array);
```